# "ReferenceError: module is not defined" when evaluating typescript statement

Tags: typescript

Here is my code

```
// properties.ts
export const properties = {
    title: "Google"
};

// example.ts
import { properties } from './properties.ts';

console.log(properties.title); // Prints Google
console.log(eval("properties.title")); // Expected to print Google but throws ReferenceError: properties is not defined
```

However,
console.log(eval('properties_1.properties.title')) // Prints Google

But how to derive "properties_1" is my concern.

Answer (score 3):

The import statement in TS transpiles to a new variable. This is by default in typescript and **eval** cannot **compute** that.

I tried like this and it worked,

```
import { properties } from './properties';
let p = properties;
console.log(p.title); // Prints Google
console.log(eval('p.title'));
```

Another way you can do this by importing properties into variable,

```
import * as properties  from './properties';
console.log(properties.properties.title); // Prints Google
console.log(eval('properties.properties.title')); // Prints Google
```

Make sure you compile this way,

```
>tsc dynamic.ts -t ES6 -m commonjs
```